# Extrude inward, while preserving faces

Tags: faces, extrude

When I extrude (vertex normals) outward, I give these faces some volume, making it no longer just plain flat faces:

https://gyazo.com/f21c91780b37273c3325a90b0a1ef6c5 (gif)

However, when I attempt to do the same but inward, you see that it does not give exactly the volume the way it does when I do it outward:

https://gyazo.com/5856edbaa9d5d491a2ad230f844078ab (gif)

I'm trying to create a shape similar to this:
[image]

I want to give the columns extrusion volume, but inward, not outward!

Comment: try to give volume by solidify modifier

Comment: @ateks Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: if it is confirm then i can post that as a answer

Comment: Yes it worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the basic shape

Add solidify modifier (with positive number)

Go in edit mode and select the top circle and Press Alt+D to duplicate

With duplicate just separate pressing "P"-> selection

Extrude the circle and to make extruding inside or inward

In the solidify modifier tab (with the same number just add a negative sign infront of it)

[image]